# Sublime Text 2 make fuzzy search ignore specific characters?

Tags: sublimetext2, fuzzy-search

In a specific project of mine which is using Zend_Framework, a file reference is named `Gen_Company_Mapper_Mysql` which maps to a file locate at `Gen/Company/Mapper/Mysql.php`

Using Sublime Text 2 Goto Anything command, it won't be able to find `Gen_Company_Mapper_Mysql` because the `_` character doesn't exists in the file path.

Can I make the fuzzy search ignore a specific character?
Also could I somehow only have that for a specific project?